# Radio Button already being visually selected when next question is clicked

Tags: reactjs

I'm having trouble with my Radio button, everytime the user goes to the next page, the radio button is already on one of the answers. I tried checked & defaultChecked but both have not worked. I would really appreciate any help :)

Here is the code for it

```
const Answer = (props) => {
  const handleSelect = () => {
    props.onAnswerSelected(props.answerId, props.questionId);
  };
  return (
    <div className="radio-group">
      <input
        type="radio"
        id={props.answerId}
        name={props.questionId}
        value={props.answerId}
        onChange={handleSelect}
      />
      <div className="button">
        <label htmlFor={props.answerId}>{props.answerContent}</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const AnswerOptionList = (props) => {
  return props.answerOptions.map((answerOption, index) => (
    <Answer
      key={index}
      answerContent={answerOption.content}
      answerId={answerOption.id}
      questionId={props.questionId}
      allAnswers={props.allAnswers}
      onAnswerSelected={props.onAnswerSelected}
    />
  ));
};
```

And here is the code sandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-antonelli-ekzesm?file=/src/components/Answer.js

Comment: Your codesandbox example isn't working - one of the first things that stands out to me is you're using the array `index` as the `key` prop. This is generally discouraged in React – do you have a more stable, unique identifier you can use for the key? Such as the `answerOption.id`?

Comment: Charlie Stanard thank you SO MUCH!!! IT WORKED!!! *tears of joy* Really appreciate your help